# Controller returns 404 when Spring Boot is started from WSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 18.04 and can't figure out why I can't call my endpoints when I start the Spring Boot Application within WSL2.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/task")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaskController {


    @GetMapping
    public String add() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I send the following Request with Postman from my Windows machine:

```
http://localhost:8080/task
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-09-14T19:52:27.350+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/task"
}
```

Response when I start the Spring Boot Application on Windows:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is because the wsl have another IP. So in OS Windows you have to put

> http://<ip_wsl>:8080/task

.

Answer (score 0):

In wsl2 you can normally only run the springboot application through a `file.jar` or docker image that is inside wsl2, so if you are using docker follow the steps below.

Try starting the image by creating another container with the following command:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 id/project:latest`

Where:

- id = your ID of docker
- project = name of repository/project
- latest = version

Now try to post again by ip http://localhost:8080/task

Comment: Any questions leave a comment here